# Spark-Scala Malformed Line Issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, malformed

I have a control-A delimited file which I am trying to convert to parquet format. However in the file there is a String field with a single " in it.

Reading the data like below:

```
val dataframe = sparkSession.sqlContext.read
                .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                .option("delimiter", datasetDelimiter)
                .option("header", "false")
                .option("mode","FAILFAST")
                //.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
                .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls","true")
                .option("nullValue"," ")
                .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
                .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")
                .schema(schema)
                .load(fileLocation)
                dataframe
```

As you can see there is just an open double quote in the data and no closed double quote. This is resulting in Malformed Line exception. While reading I have explicitly mention the delimiter as U0001. Is there any way to convert such data to parquet without losing any data

Comment: I'm assuming this is for Spark1?

Comment: Why are you using CSV format for that? Why not go straight with `text` and split the lines accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `quote` option to *empty String*:

```
.option("quote", "") 
// or, equivalently, .option("quote", '\u0000')
```

That would tell Spark to treat `"` as any other non-special character.

(tested with Spark 2.1.0)

Comment: we are dealing with several files and it is impossible to know which character will not appear in the data.

Comment: Got you - turns out there's a better option - see updated answer

Comment: @Mg2729 Also, consider setting the "escape" option to something non-problematic, or you may have further unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @TzachZohar Thnaks for your suggestions, I made the changes, but it is still not working

Comment: Does it fail with the same error, or a different one? And which Spark version are you using? Asking because it did work for me with your example data.

Comment: This is a little weird.. When i run for jst that record, it runs fine but with the whole set it fails again...

Comment: I am using spark version 2.0.2

Comment: @TzachZohar The issue is that the code does not parse the record if the column starts with a double quote. If there is a random double  quote in the column then it poses no issue. Any idea what we can do about columns starting with a " and without an ending "

Comment: I saw that the issue only reproduces when the double quote immediately follows the column delimiter (i.e. at the beginning of the column) - I've used such an example in my tests and saw it failing, then I added the suggested option and is passed... in other words - this solution "works for me" for that exact scenario you're describing (I even tried again with Spark 2.0.2) - so I'm not sure what we're missing and how to help further... sorry.